# CDVNotification plugin not working in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

i am trying to have a custom alert in my cordova based iOS application. i have installed the CDVNotification plugin using the CLI with the following commands:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-vibration.git
```

so my config.xml has the following code:

```
<feature name="Notification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
    </feature>
```

i tried to call an alert by the following piece of code:

```
navigator.notification.alert("Message Here",alertCB,"Success","ok");
```

but the alert does not seem to show and the code after that is not working as well. seems to me as if there is an error somewhere, but i am unable to get to know why. i have put the event listener for device ready as well, though the alert still does not show.

what may be the reason for it?

Comment: @user2739737: did you get any solution to ur issue. i am facing a similar issue .

Comment: i could not locate the solution, though i started using customized alert plugins using CSS

Comment: I am having the same problem. any solution/insight for help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't invoked the class. Please make changes as given,

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
```

Hope it will help you :)